# How do I use github packages in go?

Tags: go

Sorry, very much a newbie golang question.  I have a github project named journalbeat that I am modifying.

When I clone that repository I can set the GOPATH and run `go get` to grab all the imports and it places them into src.

I have a new import I want to add.

```
import "github.com/danwakefield/fnmatch"
```

but it doesn't grab it.  How does simply running `go get` determine whether something is downloaded or not?

And finally, the vendoring system is used.  How do I populate that with the fnmatch? do I create it manually?  it all seems very cumbersome.

I thought go get was meant to make all this easy?

Comment: This github project you are modifying, is it your own, or a forked one?

Comment: Forked copy of journalbeat. I'm just wondering why go get doesn't automatically grab that as well.  It's like magic.  I don't think I should have to look at the go source code to figure it out.

Comment: `go get` checks your `GOPATH` whether you have a given import path. If exists it doesn't do anything. If you would like to update to latest version use  `-u` args with `go get`. Then it refreshes your import path to latest version.

Comment: go get -u prints out: package _/home/matthewh/dev/journalbeat: unrecognized import path "_/home/matthewh/dev/journalbeat" (import path does not begin with hostname)

Comment: go package management feels awful.  Is there a decent writeup on how it works? when following examples they don't work against the above import.  Why not?

Comment: Basically, `go get` gets some packages.  I was expecting to see `src/github.com/elastic|mheese|danwakefield`  but danwakefield was missing from src.  How does `go get` know to grab the others but what stopped it from not getting `danwakefield/fnmatch`?  Is there a hidden file I need to update?

Comment: Import path starts after `src` directory `$GOPATH/src/<import-path>`. `go get` knows the dependencies packages via referenced/imported packages in your project. If you would like to get all the packages used by your project try `go get -u <your-import-path>/...` or go to your project directory run `go get -u ./...` Please read about [Remote import path](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

Comment: @Matt are you sure your `$GOPATH` and everything is set up? Sounds like you are missing some config or something. It's not complicated, it should be rather simple. Be aware that developing in go is a little different, you don't have a project dir with all it's libs and code in it. Instead, your entire `$GOPATH` is shared with everything. Your own project resides in `$GOPATH/src/<project>`, but everything else is shared unless you choose to use the vendoring system.

Comment: @ReyfenWindspear - GOPATH is set.   I'm running go get from GOPATH.  I understand it's a bit more than different.  Quite frustrating.  Very poorly documented

Comment: It sounds like your actual import statement uses `"_/home/matthewh/dev/journalbeat"` which is not going to work unless you've checked out the package into `$GOPATH/src/_/home/matthewh/dev/journalbeat`, which would be odd. If you don't fight *against* go, it works a lot better.

Comment: Ok it's starting to make more sense now.  It's because I would usually git clone.  But that seems to be not what should be done with golang.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead a dependency manager: the most recent and actively developed one is **[golang/dep](https://github.com/golang/dep)**.
Reading [**dep** "issue" 943](https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/943), use:

```
dep ensure
```

That will set up vendored dependencies through import analysis, and you can configure locking those down if need be.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that a try next week.

Comment: @Matt I have edited the answer to reference the right go dep project.

Comment: Thanks.  It appears that journalbeat might have been using something like govendor as it has a vendor.json file in the vendors folder.
It's all working great now.  I did have some project layout issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try `go get` with the verbose flag `-v` like:

`go get -v github.com/danwakefield/fnmatch`

This will show you more details. Post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

we use Glide package management tool for GO. Go check it out [gitHub link](http://github.com/Masterminds/glide)